# How to send packets to virtualbox's network card

Tags: networking, interface, virtualbox

I know VirtualBox can configure bridge adpater and open promisc options, it will get all packets that the host machine gets.

But if I want do some specific test, like run DPDK in VirtualBox. How can I replay pcap file to virtual machine's nic so the DPDK program can receive those packets?

Answer (score 0):

In KVM-QEMU each virtual (not SRIOV/VF) port of quest has an equivalent port representation  on host os. This is same interface you add to host Bridge.

To identify the port representation, use `brctl show` to identify the host NIC.

To send packets to interface, use `tcpreplay/pktgen/ping/arping`.

To observe packets on the host for traffic coming from guest port, `tcpdump -eni [interface on host] -Q in`